# Access Violation with P/Invoke SendMessage and Message.GetLParam

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I get an **intermittent** error when calling Message.GetLParam, getting messages sent between processes.
I have two processes, both written in C# (.Net 3.5). I am using the Win32 function SendMessage() to send data from one process (the source) to the other (the target). The target process's main window (it's a Windows Forms app) overrides the WndProc() function to receive messages.
The source process locates the other by using the Process.GetProcessesByName() function, then using the Process.MainWindowHandle to get the window handle that I want to send the message to. The code of the source looks like this:

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyTargetProcess");
if (procs != null 
    && procs.Length > 0)
{
    IntPtr win = procs[0].MainWindowHandle;
    var someData = new Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT   // This is a struct that I defined
    {
    // Initialize fields of the struct
    };
    Win32.SendMessage(win,
        Win32.MyMsgCode,    // my custom message
        IntPtr.Zero,    // wParam = 0
        ref someData);
}
```

The target process code looks like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == Win32.MyMsgCode)
    {
    Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT ds;
        try
        {
            ds = (Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(typeof(Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.ErrorFormat("Got exception in WndProc", ex);
        }
        // Do something with the message
        ....
}
```

Win32 is a static class I defined that gets all my P/Invoke definitions.
I do not understand why I am catching an AccessViolationException in WndProc.
Does anybody have an idea why? and why it only happens some of the time?

Thanks for your attention!

-------------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------------
Another thing that baffles me: the COPYDATASTRUCT is declared as

```
public static readonly int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004a;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    // Specifies data to be passed to the receiving application.
    public string dwData;
    // Specifies the size, in bytes, of the data pointed to by the lpData member. 
    public int cbData;
    // Pointer to data to be passed to the receiving application. This member can be NULL.                 
    public string lpData;
}
```

It is initialized like this:

```
string payload = " some data ";
var someData = new Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT   // This is a struct that I defined
{
    dwData = "bogusData",
    cbData = sizeof(char) * payload.Length,
    lpData = payload
};
```

And in target code, I always receive dwData = null.

----------------------- 2nd edit --------------------------------------
I just tried with adding the zero terminator, and I still get the error. 
If I change the marshalling code to do my own marshalling as in

```
IntPtr pcds = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(someData));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(someData, pcds, true);
Win32.SendMessage(win, (uint)Win32.WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, pcds);
```

Then the error happens ALL THE TIME! However, if I repeat the GetLParam() call in the catch block, it succeeds almost all the time, on the 2nd try.

Comment: Are you aware that `MyMsgCode` has to be `WM_COPYDATA` for this to work? How is `COPYDATASTRUCT` declared?

Comment: Yes, actually it is WM_COPYDATA.

Comment: Another thing that baffles me: the COPYDATASTRUCT is declared as

Comment: You need to show your p/invoke and the struct declaration. Edit your question to show this.

Comment: Could it be that `System.strings` cannot be so easily passed inside structs with pinvoke? I would first downgrade the structure to containt an `int` only and repeat the test.

Comment: @Wiktor They are marshalled to `LPCTSTR` which is just fine. Otherwise P/invoke would be useless!

Comment: I thought the problem is not passing `strings` per se but passing them "so easily" (by setting the length manually with proposed formula). I wonder then if your answer will turn out to be the one.

Comment: You still didn't show how you defined SendMessage.

Comment: And why did you marshal the COPYDATASTRUCT yourself. I see no reason to do that ever on the send. On the receive you should do that but, not while you are debugging this. Try changing one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that jumps out at me is that `cbData` is set incorrectly. You need to account for the zero-terminator at the end of the string.

```
 cbData = sizeof(char) * (payload.Length+1)
```

That would certainly explain the error. When you send the message, the `WM_COPYDATA` marshalling would not copy the zero terminator and so the recipient would then read beyond the end of the buffer into uninitialized values.

I also wonder about `sizeof(char)`. Are you calling the Unicode version of SendMessage? If not then I'd expect to see access violations in the sending code.

You should also be wary that the recipient application opens itself to buffer overruns. Because it ignores the value of `cbData` and treats the `lpData` field as a null-terminated pointer it may be possible for an attacker to force your app to execute arbitrary code. To defend against this, you should copy the data, `cbData` bytes of it, into a byte array and then convert to a string.

The other issue is that you need to declare `dwData` as `UIntPtr`. The way you have defined the struct, the recipient code treats `dwData` as a pointer to a string which will provoke AVs because you have crossed process boundaries.

I'd also point out that `cbData` is unsigned and should be `uint` but that is a benign error here.

Comment: Yes, looking at the MSDN doc for WM_COPYDATA, I see that dwData is a DWORD, not a pointer to a string, so UINTPtr or System.UInt32 would make sense. It does not explain why the error is internmittent only. If the zero terminator was never marshalled, why does the call sometimes succeed?

Comment: On the contrary, intermittent behaviour is exactly what you should expect. Uninitialized memory often contains zero. There may be more wrong with your code but this bit is wrong for sure.

Comment: dwData is an uint.  cbData must be sizeof(byte) * (payload.Length+1) since the string is marshaled with CharSet.Ansi in effect.  Really ought to use Encoding.Default.GetBytes() to avoid accidents.  Or change to CharSet.Unicode so the string doesn't get mangled.

Comment: When correcting for the length of the string AND declaring dwData as a System.UInt32, I never get the exception anymore.,

Comment: When correcting the length for the zero terminator AND changing dwData to a System.UInt32, I never get the exception anymore. Thank you sooooo much!!

Comment: @HansPassant We never saw SendMessage p/invoke which determines the charset. If it used Unicode then sizeof(char) would be fine.

Comment: @HansPassant But although I realised that `dwData` was wrong I hadn't cottoned on to the error that would produce on the recipient's p/invoke marshalling. That was in fact probably the major problem here.

Comment: @Hans That's on the receiving side. Surely the `sizeof(char)` only affects the sending which I believe is determined by the SendMessage DllImport attribute.

Comment: It is determined by the [StructLayout] attribute, not the SendMessage declaration.  Note the Marshal.StructureToPtr() call.  The dangling string pointer isn't happy either, that's going to blow on a garbage collection.  Best thing to do is change the  SendMessage() and make the last argument `ref Win32.COPYDATASTRUCT` so the string gets properly pinned.

Comment: @Hans Look at the original code rather than the updates. That's exactly as you describe. That's what I'm talking about.